# show single row for multiple records with total number records as count in a new column of dataframe spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data as follows.

[image]

I want to summarize this as follows:

[image]

I want to take first timestamp of name and add total count for name column.

I am not getting any Idea on how to do this in Spark scala code.

Could you please let me know how to handle this situation in spark scala dataframe.

Thanks,Bab

Comment: Hi @Bad, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your information and sure I will try to provide more details..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark SQL has functions that you can use to achieve this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{first, col}
```

In Scala you can do something like this:

```
df.groupBy(col("Name"))
  .agg(first("ID").alias("ID"),
       first(col("Timestamp")).alias("Timestamp"),
       count(col("Name")).alias("Count")
  )
```

If you want to group on both ID and Name you can also write it as

```
df.groupBy(col("ID"), col("Name"))
  .agg(first(col("Timestamp")).alias("Timestamp"),
       count(col("Name")).alias("Count")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Sailesh. This is what I am looking for and thank you for your quick response.